# Bootstrap Table not Responsive inside modal

Tags: css, html-table, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Hi I am new new to bootstrap. I wanted to make a table and make it responsive however I created a table already but its not responsive when its viewing in small devices. I'm not sure what did I miss . Can someone help me? Thank you

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .text-violet {
        color: #280d5f !important;
      }

      .text-light-violet {
        color: #7a6eaa;
        font-size: 14px !important;
      }

      .table-title-box > * {
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }

      .image {
        background-image: url("https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1886158-200.png");
        width: 45px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }

      .vertical {
        position: relative;
        height: 70px;
      }
      .has-text-lblue {
        color: #1fc7d4;
      }
      .pools {
        width: 99px;
        height: 90px;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: fixed;
        right: 9%;
        top: 0px;
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-info btn-lg"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal"
      >
        Open Modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="tab-title-box" style="display: table;">
                        <span
                          class="tabIcon"
                          style="vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 10px;"
                        >
                          <img
                            class="image"
                            src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1886158-200.png"
                          />
                        </span>
                        <span
                          class="vertical"
                          style="display: table-cell; margin-right: 20px;"
                        ></span>
                        <div
                          class="row"
                          style="
                            vertical-align: middle;
                            display: table-cell;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                            padding: 0 10px;
                          "
                        >
                          <div
                            class="tab-title-text minecraft-font text-violet p-0"
                          >
                            Auto First
                          </div>
                          <div
                            class="tab-info text-light-violet m-0 p-0 minecraft-font pt-2"
                          >
                            Automatic Viewing
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                      <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="row m-3 minecraft-font text-violet">
                          <span
                            class="text-light-violet m-0 p-0 minecraft-font mb-1"
                            >Recent View Listing</span
                          >
                          3.5 <br />
                          TEST
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="row m-3 minecraft-font text-violet">
                          <span
                            class="text-light-violet m-0 p-0 minecraft-font mb-1"
                            >3rd</span
                          >
                          Data List
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="row m-3 minecraft-font text-violet">
                          <span
                            class="text-light-violet m-0 p-0 minecraft-font mb-1"
                            >Total Viewing</span
                          >
                          89,687,109 Viewers
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="row m-3 minecraft-font text-violet">
                          <span
                            class="text-light-violet m-0 p-0 minecraft-font mb-1"
                            >Ends in</span
                          >
                          ----<br />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div class="row m-3 minecraft-font text-violet">
                          <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            width="16"
                            height="16"
                            fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-chevron-down"
                            viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                          >
                            <path
                              fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can access the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-dawn-x0xth?file=/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 has a wrapping class `.table-responsive` for make tables responsive creating scroll horizontal:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
             <!-- table content-->
        </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works too for bootstrap 4